# Inject with embedded conditional...possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator, inject

I'm expecting `9`, but getting  `nil`. Not sure why.

```
> dfs = p.disk_items.inject { |acc, di| acc + 1 if di.type == "DiskFile" }
=> nil
```

The same problem:

```
> dfs = p.disk_items.inject(0) { |acc, di| if di.type == "DiskFile" then acc + 1 end } 
=> nil
```

Clearly there are nine occurrences where `di.type == "DiskFile"` is true:

```
> dfs = p.disk_items.inject(0) { |acc, di| puts di.type == "DiskFile" }
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
false
=> nil
```

What am I screwing up? If I can't use conditionals, then maybe there's a better way to count all the `ActiveRecord` objects in an array that satisfies a condition on an attribute.

Edit: FWIW:

```
> p.disk_items.class
=> ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_DiskItem
```

looks like [this implementation in Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb) of `count` may not accept blocks? Though I may be reading this wrong or looking in the wrong place...

Comment: When the `if` "doesn't run" the block evalutates to `nil`.

Comment: Hmm, so if block evaluates to nil, `acc` should still have a value and i thought that was what is returned by `inject`?!?  Regardless, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The value [returned] is now `nil` - the result (or the next acc will be `nil`). And yes, there is a better way. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user2246674 is correct, the if statement is returning nil, but inject should always return `acc` You can use a turnery operator to make this easy

```
dfs = p.disk_items.inject(0) { |acc, di| di.type == "DiskFile" ? acc + 1 : acc  }
```

Comment: I tried ternary returning 0 on false but I see now, the counter should be returned... I get it now! thanks!

Comment: oops. looks like I get an `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for #<DiskFile:0x007ff9c63f9658>` error when I try it with this ternary syntax.

Comment: @Meltemi Because the code was missing the default (0) accumulator (and so was assuming the first time in the sequence). I've corrected it.

Comment: Ha, thanks. Just copied it off the first example. Really though, user2246674 is right and `count` is probably the correct method to use in this case

Comment: setting start value for accumulator, `inject(0)`, did it! (though I assumed `0` was default?!? anyway, thx.

Answer (score 1):

When the `if` "doesn't run" the block evalutates to `nil`. This happens on the last case and the result (`nil`) is returned.

Consider (the long-hand):

```
if di.type == "DiskFile" then
    acc + 1
else
    acc      # so we never return nil
end
```

While there are various short-hands (i.e. ?:), I would use a `count {block}`. If needing to do something else with the values (perhaps still using in an inject "sometimes"), `select` might also be useful.

> p.disk_items.count {|di| di.type == "DiskFile"}

Comment: `[array].count` should do it; forgot about that one. so many iterators in Ruby. but, alas, this isn't working for me either... `di.type == "DiskFile"` returns `10`. but so does `di.type == "garbage00jfsledl"`. Expecting `9`.

Comment: @Meltemi I would not expect those results. Something is amiss.

Comment: See my edit (above). Perhaps I'm misinterpreting Rails source; correct me if I'm wrong. All I know is that no matter what I put in the block `count` only returns the number of in the collection...as if block wasn't there.

Comment: @Meltemi I don't use Rails, but shame on it if `Enumerable.count {block}` isn't being honored for the collection. A `select {block}/count` pair should work. Maybe :)